# Is it good to publish the software and development technologies?

Tags: web-development

I did some research on developers in my area. I was mainly interested in their products and the kind of tools they used in building them. I want to make this information public, but I was just wondering if it is a good idea.

What I mean is, if the developer used Apache, MySQL and PHP and I made this public, does it make it easier for people to hack their product?

Comment: [Information Wants To Be Free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_wants_to_be_free) (I just wanted to say that)

Comment: @pst: I think the OP is asking more about advertising/being open about which tools a particular product uses.

Comment: Information like this is often helpful for developers who need to choose a stack of technologies to use in their own project. On the other hand, it doesn't make it that much easier for hackers - they can usually figure it out on their own, and a lot more too.

Comment: If you're making a website that is there to sell things, and you're using valuable space to provide free advertising for development tools... well something's not right! If you're a developer making a portfolio, surely you're selling YOUR skills and services, not the platform behind it?

Answer (score 1):

it depends. all the tools you mentioned are "safe" if configured correct (leaving 0 day exploits beside). if configured the right way, you cant even tell what tools the backend is using. in generell: every info a hacker may get about your system makes your system weaker. thats why many devs dont talk about what they're using.

if you want to publish the informations, best ask the devs. i think most of them will allow you to publish the infos you want to publish.

Comment: Thanks, It basically a portfolio of what developers in my country are doing. I wanted to see how active the developer community is and which tools are more popular

Answer (score 0):

To add to what **masi**:

It's not just easier to hack it , but depending on sites target audience, it can be either pointless or even harmful. Only case where publishing technical details could be useful is in a site that is developer-oriented and if you are using some technology or methodology which has been *hyped* lately.

Case and point : 37signals , they time to time publish some small tidbits about internal workings in the blogs. But it is aimed at very specific audience. Such details would only harms an online "Wine cellar".

Comment: The site is developer oriented and I am thinking of allowing the devs login and list their products. They will decide whether or not to specify the tools they used

Comment: @kkd then maybe advise them to share the methodology, techniques and stuff about development tools , but NOT details of server(s) and list of 3rd party libraries the happened to use.